# Magento observe save only special product type

Tags: magento, observers

I'm writing a custom module, where i've added a custom product type. How can i write an observer catalog_product_save_after only for that custom product type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add an observer for that type of product, but you can check in the observer if the product is valid. If not then do nothing.

```
public function doSomething($observer){
   $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
   if ($product->getTypeId() != 'YOUR TYPE HERE'){
       return $this;
   }
   //your magic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*_save_after` events are fired from the `Varien_Object` class, and is dynamic depending on the class. So it is gonna be the same event for all product types.

You can still observe the catalog_product_save_after event and perform your actions depending on the product type :

```
public function yourObserverMethod($observer)
{          
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    if($product == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE) {
        // Your stuff
    }

}
```